# Python: POSTing binary data gives UnicodeDecodeError or Ascii decode error

Tags: python-2.7

When POSTing binary data using urllib2 or urllib3, or httplib2, I receive the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode` or `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode...` depending on whether the Python script is in UniCode or ASCII mode.

I first thought that the library was the issue, so I tried different libraries but that didn't solve the problem.

End of the stack trace:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 895, in _send_output
    msg += message_body
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 627: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as noted in comments to Python [bug 11898](http://bugs.python.org/issue11898) is that the url string became tagged at some point as either a Unicode or Ascii string.

Then, when the httplib library is creating the byte string for the entire HTTP/S message, and the line

```
msg += message_body
```

is executed, Python tries to convert `message_body` (which contains binary data) to either Ascii or Unicode. In either case, the conversion fails.

**Solution**
use `str()` when making any modifications to the url. In my case:

```
url = baseUrl + "/envelopes"      # throws UnicodeDecodeError
url = str(baseUrl + "/envelopes") # works great
```

If that is not enough, check your other strings to ensure that they haven't been tagged as Unicode or Ascii.